# Conditional Expectations for any value

Tags: probability, conditional-expectation, expected-value

How to make sense of $E[X | Y]$? where $X$ and $Y$ are independent random variables.

Now if we consider for a particular value of $y$ which $Y$ takes

$$
\begin{align}
E[X | Y = y] &= \sum_x x P(X = x | Y = y) \\ 
&= \sum_x x f_{X|Y}(x, y) \\ 
&= \sum_x x \frac{P(X = x, Y = y)}{P(Y = y)} \\ 
&= \sum_x x P(X = x) \\ 
&= E[X]
\end{align}
$$

How do we go about and prove that $E[X | Y] = E[X]$ ? i.e, true for any value $y$? It doesn't really make sense to write $P(Y)$ If we proceed with similar proof as above,

$$
\begin{align}
E[X | Y] &= \sum_x x P(X = x | Y) \\ 
&= \sum_x x f_{X|Y}(x) \\ 
&= \sum_x x \frac{P(X = x, Y)}{P(Y)} \\ 
\end{align}
$$

I am stuck at this point. Thanks.

Comment: Isn't the particular $y$ also any $y$?

Comment: yes, that's right as per intuition but I just wanted that in a neat mathematical form

Comment: Note that $E[X|Y = y]$ is a number and a function of $y$. $E[X|Y]$ is a random variable and a function of $Y$. So, in a sense you can say that $E[X|Y = y]$ is a realization of the random variable $E[X|Y]$ .

Comment: Agreed. Could you just put that into a nice mathematical representation as is done for $E[X | Y = y]$

Answer (score 0):

$\mathbb E[X\mid Y]$ is a random variable  measurable wrt to the $\sigma$-algebra generated by random variable $Y$.

That means that a Borelmeasurable function $f:\mathbb R\to\mathbb R$ exists with $\mathbb E[X\mid Y]=f(Y)$.

So what you actually found out in the case of independent $X$ and $Y$ is: $$f(y)=\mathbb E[X\mid Y=y]=\mathbb EX$$i.e. the function $f$ is *constant* and takes value $\mathbb EX$ for every $y$.

If $Z$ is a degenerated random variable with $Z(\omega)=c$ for every $\omega\in\Omega$ then this can be expressed as: $$Z=c$$Applying this here we get:$$\mathbb E[X\mid Y]=\mathbb EX$$where the LHS is a random variable and the RHS is an element of $\mathbb R$.